# Give a context-free grammar

Tags: context-free

We know that $L$ = { $w$ $\in$ {a, b}* $|$ $|w|_{a}$ > $|w|_{b}$ }

This is my answer: $G$ = ({$S$,$A$,$B$},{$a$,$b$},$R$,$S$)

$R$ = S $\to$ $AB$

$A$ $\to$ $aA | Aa |B$

$A$ $\to$ $a | abB | Bab | Bba |aBb|bBa $

But after testing, it seems that writing like this is wrong.

So how should it be written?

https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1156/tools/cfg/

This link can be used to simulate.

Comment: Are you checked my answer?

Comment: Yes, I think your answer is correct, thank you very much！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is finding a CFG grammar $G$ for the language $L$ that contains equal number of $a's$ and $b's$ with extra number of $a's$ .
$$L=\{\omega\in \Sigma^*\mid n_a(\omega)>n_b(\omega)\}$$

Let $A$ is a variable that derive only $a's$.

Let $E$ is a variable that derive equal number of $a's$ and $b's$.

Let $S$ be start symbol.

As a result we have the following grammar $G$:

$$S\to EAE\mid SS$$
$$E\to EE\mid aEb\mid bEa\mid \lambda$$
$$A\to aA\mid a$$